# ng-hide class stays even with true value for ng-show

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In my code, the ng-hide value becomes `true` at some point in the controller (after an async function is resolved) but the ng-hide class stays on the element:

```
             <div class="averageRatingContainer" ng-show="data.showStars">
                    <div class="star-ratings-css">
                        <div class="star-ratings-css-top" ng-style="{width: data.avgRating + '%'}">
                            <span><i class="ion-ios-star"></i></span>
                            <span><i class="ion-ios-star"></i></span>
                            <span><i class="ion-ios-star"></i></span>
                            <span><i class="ion-ios-star"></i></span>
                            <span><i class="ion-ios-star"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="star-ratings-css-bottom">
                            <span><i class="ion-ios-star"></i></span>
                            <span><i class="ion-ios-star"></i></span>
                            <span><i class="ion-ios-star"></i></span>
                            <span><i class="ion-ios-star"></i></span>
                            <span><i class="ion-ios-star"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

in the controller :

```
 $scope.data.showStars = false;

$scope.getAvgRating = function() {
            pouchDBservice.getAverageRating($scope.prodata[$scope.data.computed.proId].modelStrict, function (result) {  //...ASYNC
                if (!result) {
                    console.log('...shit !');
                    $scope.data.avgRating = 0;
                    $scope.data.numberOfRatings = 0;
                    $scope.data.showStars = true;
                    console.log("getting avg rating done")            
                } else {
                    $scope.data.averageRating = result.averageRating;
                    $scope.data.numberOfRatings = result.numberOfRatings;
                    console.log('average rating: ', $scope.data.averageRating, ', number of ratings: ', $scope.data.numberOfRatings  );
                    $scope.data.avgRating = $scope.data.averageRating*100/5;
                    $scope.data.showStars = true;
                    console.log("getting avg rating done")
                }
            } );
        }
```

So when the function is done, `$scope.data.showStars`becomes `true` and the ng-hide class should disappear.

Comment: are the other data properties getting updated correctly?  how is the call to `getAvgRating()` getting triggered?  maybe you need a `$scope.$apply()`